# Exporting the truth table from QCA package in R

Tags: r, export

This almost drove me crazy today, so i figured I share it:

If you are working with the QCA (Qualitative Comparative Analysis) package in R, you can create so called truth tables. They are an essential part in the process of data analysis, so if you want to report your findings, it would be very useful to be able to export the truth table.

One option export is to jus copy the output from R. This is not very convenient however, because it means that you are limited to a fixed-width font like courier new.

You can export tables in R using the `write.table()` function, however, the `truthtable()` function does not create a dataframe as output, so you can not export it as table.

Thus, the question is how do you export the truth table  as an actual table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, but hard to find if you don't know where to look.

if you write the truth table into a variable, you can access the object `tt`within that variable for the corresponding data frame. The export shoud look like this:

```
myTable <- truthtable(parameters.....)
write.table(myTable$tt, file = "filename.txt", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

I hope this saves someone the painful process I had to go through to find this out. For more information check out the reference below.

Thiem, A., & Dusa, A. (2013). Qualitative Comparative Analysis with R.